# Unit testing for post API for a Google workflows endpoint

Tags: java, junit5, google-workflows

I have a post API endpoint where I post certain data into the workflow. I am unable to mock certain static methods using Mockito and jnuit5. I am using methods including `ExecutionName.of()`, `executionClient.getExecution()` and `getExecutionRequest()`. Fresher in a company, any suggestions on how to do it.

I have tried stub injection but wasn't able to get any results out of it.

Comment: I suggest you add the code of what you are trying to do, in that way, we can have a starting point and a clear idea of what you want to reach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.